# drop down div inside a parent with overflow set to hidden

Tags: html, css, overflow

Ive got the following for the parent div:

```
#parent {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

And the following for the inner div which is a drop down div. When click to show, a part of the drop down which goes below the parent div, is not displayed (only half displayed).

```
#dropDown {

display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
```

and here is my HTML code:

```
<div id='parent'>


<ul>
    <li id="exportWrapper">
        <button onclick="return false" id="triggerDropDown">trigger </button>
       <div id="dropDown">
         <span  class="one"> link one</span><br>
         <span  class="two"> link two</span>
       </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why `overflow: hidden`?

Comment: what is the `#dropDown` id in your HTML code?

Comment: @ExplosionPills I am putting the parent beside another div and I want them both to be in same line thats why I have to use overflow hidden unless there is a better way

Comment: @KevinPaladin sorry I edited it

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see anything that called the #dropDown css. I changed the div#exportDivContent to div#dropDown and it hides the two . Is that you are trying to do?

`<ul>
    <li id="exportWrapper">
        <button onclick="return false" id="triggerDropDown">trigger </button>
      <div id="dropDown">
         <span  class="one"> link one</span><br>
         <span  class="two"> link two</span>
       </div>
    </li>
</ul>`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think the problem here is you setting `overflow: hidden` to the `parent` div. So, at first there is no overflow and the button is displayed properly. Then, when you click on the button, the height of it increases since there is a drop down list and hence, it shows only half of the list.

Try removing `overflow: hidden` [Edit] : or this:

```
<button onclick="a_function()" id="triggerDropDown">trigger </button>
   <div id="dropDown">
     <span  class="one"> link one</span><br>
     <span  class="two"> link two</span>
   </div>
<script>
   function a_function(){
      document.getElementById("parent").style.height = "60px";
   }
</script>
```

Comment: I know that the overflow: hidden is causing it, I was looking for a solution. overflow: hidden is the best solution I found to set two divs in one line. do you know a better solution that I can get rid of this annoying css property?

Comment: does the height of the `parent` div increase when the button is clicked? try using some background color for that div to find that out.